# In React, why not have a component and hook combined?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As far as I can tell the usual/recommended way in React is to have state and pass it with the setter to a component, e.g.

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
return <>{/* stuff */} <MyStringInput value={name} setValue={setName} </>;
```

It feels weird to me that we have this `setName` function when we don't actually want to manually use it in this scope, also, `MyStringInput` assumes `setValue` is the setter for `value` but this is not enforced. I would think something like this would be nicer:

```
const [name, nameInput] = myStringInput("");
return <>{/* stuff */} {nameInput} </>;
```

But reading materials on react it seems you're supposed to either have a hook returning no JSX or a component returning only JSX. What are the flaws if any in the second approach?

Comment: You say _"the usual/recommended way in React is to have state and pass it with the setter to a component"_, but I'd generally recommend **not** just giving the value and the setter to a child component - that way the parent totally loses control of its own state. Seeing this is often indicative of the wrong abstractions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe interesting I'm new to React so I might have missed this. Could you provide a resource (e.g. tutorial) to learn the right way of thinking here? I'm thinking, say with tailwind you want to have a component just to get the right styling, so wouldn't it have to be very general like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks are a way of *composing behaviour and state* whereas JSX/components are essentially a higher-level macro view of the application.

It can help to understand the progression of React itself to know why the pattern you describe came about in the first place. On first glance, you actually might think the older class components were more succinct in describing what you want to do, but they were also inherently less flexible.

Back before hooks existed, you had class components. In class components, the component itself is the abstraction you use for state, effects (aka lifecycle), and presentation. All of these tended to be coupled in one unit. The problem with inherently coupling the lifecycle/state with a component was that the lifecycle and state are intrinsically coupled to the presentational layer so logic becomes harder to reuse elsewhere in the app. You very often might find whilst the scope of the state is only useful to you now for a limited bit of JSX, that later on, you'll find as your app grows something else needs access to that and you need to move state (and its associated lifecycle behaviours around).

Many patterns emerged to work around this on class components like HOCs and render props (worth googling these), but those had unlikeable APIs and some had fundamental weaknesses that made composing behaviours more clumsy than it is now with hooks. Not to say they're bad, actually they often still have a place to this day in specific circumstances, especially render props.

Another aspect of class components was that the API used to access the lifecycle of class components tended to mean that in the end, you had multiple functional requirements split around your component, whereas they really should be grouped by purpose/functionality. Hooks enable the consumer to pick and choose what part of the library functionality they want to use in a neat unit of reuse.

In addition, having the hooks separate means it's easier for consumers to well...hook...the logic of some lib into a presentational style/jsx tree of their choosing, without being inherently coupled to someone else's. Form libraries are a great example of this (see react-hook-form).

This gave rise to hooks. In short, hooks means:

- As your app gets bigger and more complex, it's easier to reuse and move around the state and behaviour of that state.
- Hooks make it easier to make units of reuse that truly focus on one functional area.

Using your example, whilst you may think that *now* nothing needs access to the scope of the hook, if this assumption was baked in (as it was with class components), it's really annoying to refactor and pull apart later when you decided that something new actually *does* need that state. Hooks ensures that state and behaviour remain portable and composable. However, if this code is at the *application* level, this is where it can actually start to be *useful* to make those assumptions and create wrappers that couple them. If you are not authoring something highly reusable in many unknown contexts, that assumption is usually safe.

If you're sure that consumers will simply never care about the scope of the hook in isolation, the real answer is to simply make a component that wraps the hooks and the inner components and that component *is* the API. In libraries though, this can sometimes be a big mistake since if something else in the user's userland that is potentially "higher-up" needs access to that state, the library user is basically trapped unless they do dirty duplication tricks which inherently increase the surface area of bugs in an application.

That said, many libraries will expose easy-to-use component wrappers that keep the state with the inner components, and also expose the underlying hooks and inner components separately as a way to enable ease of use whilst also enabling power users who may need complex relationships with that state that spread across multiple areas of their codebase of their choosing.

As I commented elsewhere on this question, returning components from a hook is a bad idea. With that approach, you have basically created a component (which inherently couples hooks and other inner components) inside of a hook, instead of just using a component to do that. Such a hook's behaviour is inherently inseparable from its presentational inner components and the problems of class components start to reappear. This typically leads to scoping and performance nightmares as well as being very hard to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something similar to what you want by creating [custom hooks](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks).

*/hooks/use-input.js*

```js
const useInput = (inputProps, initialValue = '') => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const changeHandler = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const InputComponent = (
    <input {...inputProps} value={value} onChange={changeHandler} />
  );

  return InputComponent;
};

export default useInput;
```

*your-file.js*

```js
import useInput from '/hooks/use-input.js';

const Comp = props => {
  const FirstNameInput = useInput({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'first-name',
    placeholder: 'Enter your first name'
  });

  return <>{/* stuff */}{FirstNameInput}</>
};
```

But at this point, this just a regular custom input component you could create separately. So I would recommend you do so.

Comment: This way I'm not getting the value back, so it seems the input won't do anything.

Comment: Yuu can return state as well in an object in custom hook useInput

Comment: I don't see the difference with what I wrote then

Comment: @acupoftea I mean brah, that's what you asked "would be nicer" and I presented it to you. What else do you want? If you dont want to return a JSX from a custom hook (although your "would be nicer" request returns a JSX) you can separate state management/logic on just a custom hook and wrap it around a input component as the below answer suggests. You ask this and you don't like it, i don't understand what is that you want or need.

Comment: You should usually avoid returning components from hooks. This will cause many rerenders and is harder to reason about.

Comment: I'll add it defeats the point as well. The point in hooks is composability of state and its behaviour, and if you have a hook that returns a component it is now inherently coupled to a specific component. You basically just made a component inside of a hook, but with poor performance characteristics.

Comment: I know about the drawbacks of this suggestion but that's one way to get what OP asked as "would be nicer", so here it is. I have also mentioned what else could be done to prevent this drawbacks in my previous comments.

Comment: I get what you're saying. I think fundamentally what they consider "nicer" is actually not really nicer in the long run and just needs to be discouraged. The thought process that leads them to want it is in itself, what needs questioning. You could look at the hook/component coupling example and thing its actually good if you're a newbie. Hell, I actually do see that a lot in enterprise projects with lots of devs where it seems like an easy way out. I'm not being combative btw lol, there's too much of that on this site.

Comment: @adsy yeah, you are right. Instead of answering the need, should have just discouraged this way of doing things with the reasons.